# Spring JDBC - Configure Build Path warning error showing

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring, jdbc

I am new for Spring JDBC Template.
I am using Eclipse Kepler IDE and Mysql DB.
I trying to insert the data in DB using Spring JDBCTemplate, but its showing error as "Configure build path".(refer the screen shot)
I have added all the related JARS in my project build path.
Kindly advise me how to resolve this issue .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click "Configure build path" (in your screenshot), a window will emerge.

OR

Right click on your project (in project explorer) ->Configure ->Build Path

1. In the emerging window, you will find four tabs, select "Libraries".There, under You can find "Web app libraries" OR "Maven Dependencies" (after expand it)

2.You will see the libraries added to the project's classpath. look out for JDBC jar and IMPORT it into your project.

Try to remove and add spring-jdbc jar as external jar as below.

```
Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs
```

Answer (score -1):

Same error I faced once and by changing or downgrading the version of spring framework helped me to resolve this error.

Old maven dependency ---

[image]

and changed to -----

[image]